# Facebook setting change

Tags: facebook

When I share something on Facebook, the app automatically opens lots of related stuff. For example, if I share a photo by Zio Ematitos, "More photos by Zio Ematitos", "These friends also like Zio Ematitos" and "More posts from Zio Ematitos" appear over the News feed (or whatever I was sharing from, together with "(circled checkmark) Posted        DONE". I don't want that to happen. Is there a setting to turn this off?